# Checking whether a folder exists under an IIS application using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, directoryservices, virtual-directory

I'm working on a web based deployment tool in C# which deploys applications remotely on IIS 7.

I've reached a point where where I'm able to deploy an application. Now I need to see if the application that is deployed has a a certain directory before attempting to set permissions on it (Since the tool would deploy different applications which may or may not have that folder).

There are two approaches that I took:

- I've checked for classes that I can use under the `ServerManager` namespace. I can get a handle on an application deployed under a certain application pool using:

  `var iis = ServerManager.OpenRemote("serverName")`

  `var iisApplication = iis.Sites[site].Applications["appName"];`.

  Now I can get the virtual directories under the application using :

  `var virtualDirectory = iisApplication.VirtualDirectories;`

  But then I'm not able to see a whole lot of folders which are under that virtual directory. For axample, my application is deployed as test and `iisApplication.VirtualDirectories.First()` gives me `/test`. I was want to be able to `/test/_ApplicationLogs` which is the directory I want to set permissions on.
- My next approach was to use `DirectoryEntry`. Here, I'm not able to figure out the metabase path to use for my application.  Is there a standard metabase path used for IIS 7?

  For an application called `test` deployed locally, what would the metabase path be? And would I be able to get all the children so that I can use `DirectoryEntry.Exists`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I have a workaround. I can use the `WhatIf` (set it true) property under `DeploymentSyncOptions`, do a sync and then check if an object got added. If it did, the directory does not exist. Code :

```
var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions();
syncOptions.WhatIf = true;

using (deploymentObject)
{
   var result = deploymentObject.SyncTo(
   DeploymentWellKnownProvider.SetAcl,
   "Default Web Site/path_to_folder",
   destinationBaseOptions,
   syncOptions);

   if (result.ObjectsAdded != 0)
   {
     syncOptions.WhatIf = false;
     deploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.SetAcl,
                            "Default Web Site/path_to_folder",
                             destinationBaseOptions,
                             syncOptions);
   }
}
```